# SSO for nginx using OAuth

Tags: nginx

I am looking to setup SSO for an application using an nginx webserver. As nginx doesn't have any OAuth support modules (correct me if I am wrong here), can you please suggest any OAuth support tool to use with nginx, especially when the OAuth provider is Oracle Access Manager.